# Perl pipe open issue with ' in command

Tags: perl, file-io, pipe

I am puzzled, simple code fails to return error for PIPE2 open, but does it for similar PIPE3!
 I read perl processes pipe openings differently if there are any meta characters, but I do not know how to write code with correct error check for invalid pipe. How can I check PIPE2 open failed? `$?` or `$!` did not pickup error either.
Thanks.

```
open(PIPE2,"|/bin/echod 'sometxt'")||die "Pipe2 cannot open\n";
print PIPE2 "echoed 2\n";
close PIPE2;

open(PIPE3,"|-","/bin/echod sometxt")||die "Pipe3 cannot open\n";
print PIPE3 "echoed 3\n";
close PIPE3;
```

From command prompt after execution:

```
sh: /bin/echod: No such file or directory   
Pipe3 cannot open
```

This is `perl, v5.8.8` built for `x86_64-linux-thread-multi`

Comment: `open(PIPE3,"|-","/bin/echod sometxt");` doesn't execute `die` statement for me. While change it to `open(PIPE3,"-|/bin/echod sometxt");` It executes `die` statement.

Comment: how about 
`close(PIPE2) or die "Pipe2 Cannot open $!";`. If you are reading from the PIPE, you need to check the close() to see what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the fancy `"|-"` style, you are not specifying a shell command to run, but rather a list of arguments to be passed to the *execvp*(2) syscall.

```
open(PIPE2,"|/bin/echod 'sometxt'")      || die "Pipe2 cannot open: $!";
print PIPE2 "echoed 2\n";
close(PIPE2)                             || die "Pipe2 cannot close: $!";
```

versus

```
open(PIPE3,"|-","/bin/echod", "sometxt") || die "Pipe3 cannot open: $!";
print PIPE3 "echoed 3\n";
close(PIPE3)                             || die "Pipe3 cannot close: $!";
```

The second form is used only when you don’t want the shell expanding wildcards, interpreting pipe and redirect symbols, etc. when you pass in variables of unknown content.

The first form is for when you *do* want that to happen, or when you have constant strings or string of known content in the command. I virtually always use the first form, reserving the second form for tricky situations like

```
open(GREPPER, "grep $expr @files |")
```

because it’s a thankless and fairly impossible job trying to figure out the right quoting on `$expr` there.

Comment: No, `|-` can take a shell command. (e.g. `perl -E'open $pipe, "-|", q{perl -E'\''say "foo";'\''}; print <$pipe>;'`) It's just like `system` and `exec`.

Comment: As for the impossible job, [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::ShellQuote) on unixy systems.

Comment: what I am missing in your answer is,about `die` statement.Question is how to handle `open` function failure for `PIPE2` filehandle.i.e. die statement not executing at `open(PIPE2,"|/bin/echod 'sometxt'") || die "Pipe2 cannot open: $!";`
`.

Comment: @Devendra You actually can’t. The shell starts up, and it’s the shell that can’t run the command. You have to catch it later.

Comment: @tchrist- Thanks.Still I think we can use it at `close(PIPE2) or die "$!";`.

Comment: @Devendra Yes, that’s where it’s caught here. In a larger program, you would get SIGPIPEd.

Comment: As Devendra said, problem was not "|-" but die statement. close(PIPE2) solution works for me, THANKS everyone!

Answer (score 1):

(as discussed in comments)
In case of `open` function with pipe `|` (and not `|-` or `-|`) the open function failure can be handled at `close` of file handle.

Here's how I would do it

```
open(PIPE2,"|/bin/echod 'sometxt'");
print PIPE2 "echoed 2\n";
close(PIPE2) or die "Pipe2 Cannot open $!";
```